# create a base class object use a derived class constructor c++

Tags: c++, class, constructor, destructor, class-hierarchy

Is someone can tell why `A a = B();` call constructor fisrt and then destructor immediately？
And why the output like this?

```
C A

C B

D B

D A

test1 A

D A
```

```
class A  {
public:
    A() {
        cout<< "C A" <<endl;
    }

    ~A() {
        cout<< "D A" <<endl;
    }

    void test1() {
        cout<< "test1 A" << endl;
    }
};

class B:public A {
public:
    B() {
        cout<< "C B" <<endl;
    }

    ~B() {
        cout<< "D B" <<endl;
    }

    void test1() {
        cout<< "test1 B" << endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    A a = B();   
    a.test1();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [What is Object Slicing ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this declaration

```
 A a = B();
```

there is at first created a temporary object of the type B. So its base constructor A and the constructor of B are called.

```
C A

C B
```

The object `a` is created using the default copy constructor of the class A.

After the declaration the temporary object of the type B is destroyed calling destructors in the reverse order

```
D B

D A
```

At the end of the program the object `a` is also destroyed calling its destructor.

```
test1 A

D A
```